# Chrome extension issue while scraping the data from website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension for scraping the website. I have tried using the `XHR (XMLHttpRequest)` in the `background.js` file of my extension.

Here is the code what I tried:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  

req.open('GET', tab.url,false);   
req.send();  
if(req.status == 200)  
   alert(req.responseText);
```

Even I have tried to access through the `response.XML`

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  

req.open('GET', tab.url,false);   
req.send();  
if(req.status == 200)  
   alert(req.responseXML);
```

But not able to. What I received was the code without the comment part in the code. I have seen the that code which I am trying to access can be viewed completely from the `View Source` page of the chrome browser, but the same code cannot be viewed from the Inspect windows in the Chrome Browser.

I am unable to understand why? May be the XHR is not able to scrape the data. If this is the scenario then what I can do for the complete code scraping? I am doing the client side scraping only and no server side involved. I thought of using the node.js modules but they are not client side and have a lot of restrictions if they are made client side.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks incorrect. Ideally you will get the response on the `onreadystatechange` callback not just after send.

Try the below format

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = tab.url;

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Sure.. But I guess I tried this way too but was not working.. still I will check it.

Comment: As I said no it didn't work. It shows the result from the `Inspect Window` and not as from the `Source window`.

Comment: Is this something which is not working specific to chrome extension only or in web also. Is there any error in console ?

Comment: Well, there is no error as such. Even it is working. I have no doubt in the working of this my friend. What I have said is that the code doesn't fetch that source code from the `view source page`, instead, it shows the code what the `inspect element` shows too. But I want to extract the code from the view source page.

Comment: Ok I got your point. However you wont be able to fetch the Source Code as such. I think you will always get rendered output.

Comment: SO there isn't any solution to what I am trying to achieve? Is there no solution with the google chrome extension development? I had a look at the documentation but nothing got.

Comment: Now I get this error: `Not allowed to load local resource:`